# Using a table as criteria for a query

Tags: ms-access, database-design, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007, relational-database

I have scoured the internet for a solution to this problem, and I am at my wit's end. I am using a query to return responses from a survey(table). I need to be able to filter the query results using multiple filters. In other words, 1.) the user will choose which key-words he wants to filter by, 2.) the key-words will be appended to a table, .3) the query uses the fields in the table as criteria, and only returns the results that match **all** of the key-words in the table.

I have had moderate success by using Dlookup([fieldName],[tableName],Not "") as my query criteria, but this only filters the query by matching the first item in the table, while I need the query to be filtered by matching ALL of the items in the table.

Thank you in advance for your help!

P.S. This is my first question on SO!

EDIT:

Here is the table (FilterStack_Table) where I have stored my active filters. The "Keywords" I was referring to are in the 'Answers' field.

[Table of filters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jN5Oa.jpg)

Here is my query that returns the RespondentID(s) along with what they answered in the survey. The criteria under the Answers column is DLookUp("Answers","FilterStack_Table")

[Running Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Kk9S.jpg)

What the Query *should* return is only RespondentID 5, because only that particular respondent has both 'DAL' and 'February' in their pool of answers. Thank you for your comments so far!

Comment: I don't understand.  Are all these "key words" being filtered in the same field?

Comment: Please post what ever code you have so far.  Would you be open to a VBA solution? You could write a custom function to return all of your search criteria records in a comma seperated string and use an IN() comparison to filter your results.

Comment: @JohnnyBones yes the Keywords are all in the same field. Each Keyword is a separate record under the same "Keyword" field.

Comment: @Gene I would absolutely be open to a VBA solution. I haven't coded anything by hand in this particular database so far. I've only used macros.

Comment: Here is an image of my query design view. http://i.stack.imgur.com/wZdmD.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SQL for your query should look something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE MyField IN 
(
SELECT MyKeyFieldData
FROM MyOtherTable
)
```

Obviously, the field and table names above aren't literal, you have to replace them with your field and table names.  But this is the "template" you will use.

Comment: Thank you! I ended up using several queries in the format you provided. One query for each filter that the user added. Each one would narrow down the results until I got what I needed. Thanks again!